# How can I check if an element in the list is an empty list: []?

Tags: list, prolog

How can I check if an element in the list is an empty list: [] ?

I've got the following:

```
display_degrees([A,B,C,D]):- write(B).

display_degrees([A,B,C,D]):- B==[], nl,write('has no degree'), nl, !.
```

When I enter in something like:

```
display_degrees([1,[],3,4]).
```

I just get: [] instead of 'has no degree'.  Is my syntax wrong?  Can I not add a clause to this predicate like this?

Comment: @larsmans Is that the correct way to put it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting this behavior because proof search stops when a goal has succeeded.  When you type

```
display_degrees([1,[],3,4]).
```

the first rule unifies, and it writes B.  Since it was a success, it stops.  You can ask Prolog to keep searching, and then it will find the second clause.  In swipl, I get

```
?- [foo].
?- display_degrees([1,[],3,4]).
[]
true r  % I type 'r' there
has no degree
true.
```

If you're just learning Prolog, I suggest you avoid the cut operator ! for some time.  Also, doing IO is not the most intuitive thing.  I would try some exercises with defining things like natural numbers and recursive functions.  E.g., plus:

```
plus(z, X, X).
plus(s(X), Y, s(Z)) :- plus(X, Y, Z).
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with what you have is that the more general rule will fire first. You could switch the order:

```
display_degrees([A,[],C,D]) :- nl, write('has no degree'), nl, !.
display_degrees([A,B,C,D]) :- write(B).
```

I could just as well have written for the first predicate:

```
display_degrees([A,B,C,D]) :- B == [], nl, write('has no degree'), nl, !.
```

But the "shortcut" I show initially is more idiomatic for a Prolog predicate like this.

I kept the cut since you know you deterministically want one choice. The first rule will match if and only if the second list element is `[]`.

```
| ?- display_degrees([1,[],3,4]).

has no degree

yes
| ?- display_degrees([1,2,3,4]).
2

yes
| ?-
```